# Is the valid state domain of a program a regular language?

Tags: bug-tracking, stack-trace, formal-languages

If you look at the call stack of a program and treat each return pointer as a token, *what kind of automata is needed to build a recognizer for the valid states of the program?*

As a corollary, *what kind of automata is needed to build a recognizer for a specific bug state?*

(Note: I'm only looking at the info that could be had from [this function](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual//html_node/Backtraces.html).)

---

My thought is that if these form regular languages than some interesting tools could be built around that. E.g. given a set of crash/failure dumps, automatically group them and generate a recognizer to identify new instances of know bugs.

---

Note: I'm not suggesting this as a diagnostic tool but as a data management tool for turning a pile of crash reports into something more useful.

- "These 54 crashes seem related, as do those 42."
- "These new crashes seem unrelated to anything before date X."
- etc.

---

It would seem that I've not been clear about what I'm thinking of accomplishing, so here's an example:

Say you have a program that has three bugs in it.

- Two bugs that cause invalid args to be passed to a single function tripping the same sanity check.
- A function that if given a (valid) corner case goes into an infinite recursion.

Also as that when the program crashes (failed assert, uncaught exception, seg-V, stack overflow, etc.) it grabs a stack trace, extracts the call sites on it and ships them to a QA reporting server. (I'm assuming that only that information is extracted because 1, it's easy to get with a one time per project cost and 2, it has a simple, definite meaning that can be used without any special knowledge about the program)

What I'm proposing would be a tool that would attempt to classify incoming reports as connected to one of the known bugs (or as a new  bug).

The simplest thing would be to assume that one failure site is one bug, but in the first example, two bugs get detected in the same place. The next easiest thing would be to require the entire stack to match, but again, this doesn't work in cases like the second example where you have multiple pieces of (valid) valid code that can trip the same bug.

Comment: The two examples are the same.  The second function will have an initial stack trace leading up to where the function was called; then the huge (and uninformative) recursion.

Comment: @S. Lott: "The two examples are the same." How? Cold you elaborate? Also, for the stack overflow, the huge recursion is very useful in at least two ways. For my proposed system, it provides an easy to spot fingerprint for the bug that you can expect to see in any case that trips it. For the user of the system it give them an idea about where to start looking: http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/07/9286576.aspx

Comment: BTW, the stack traces I'm thinking of would use the idea considered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609068/cross-version-line-matching) to reduce cross version volatility.

Answer (score 0):

If your program is decorated with assert statements, then each assert statement defines a valid state.  The program statements between the assertions define the valid state changes.

A program that crashes has violated enough assertions that something broken.

A program that's incorrect but "flaky" has violated at least one assertion but hasn't failed.

It's not at all clear what you're looking for.  The valid states are -- sometimes -- hard to define but -- usually -- easy to represent as simple `assert` statements.

Since a crashed program has violated one or more assertions, a program with explicit, executable assertions, doesn't need an crash debugging.  It will simply fail an assert statement and die visibly.

If you don't want to put in assert statements then it's essentially impossible to know what state *should* have been true and which (never-actually-stated) assertion was violated.

Unwinding the call stack to work out the position and the nesting is trivial.  But it's not clear what that shows.  It tells you what broke, but not what other things lead to the breakage.  That would require guessing what assertions where supposed to have been true, which requires deep knowledge of the design.

---

Edit.

"seem related" and "seem unrelated" are undefinable without recourse to the actual design of the actual application and the actual assertions that *should* be true in each stack frame.

If you don't know the assertions that *should* be true, all you have is a random puddle of variables.  What can you claim about "related" given a random pile of values?

```
Crash 1: a = 2, b = 3, c = 4 

Crash 2: a = 3, b = 4, c = 5
```

Related?  Unrelated?  How can you classify these without knowing *everything* about the code?  If you know *everything* about the code, you can formulate standard `assert`-statement conditions that *should have been* true.  And then you know what the actual crash is.

Comment: I'm not looking at the state transition of a program but at the instantaneous state as defined only by the call stack return pointers. The thought is that it might be possible to use regular languages to differentiate crashes/assert-failures that manifest at the same point but are caused by different root causes. This *would* be a heuristic so it shouldn't be expected to work all the time but if you are in triage mode, very much alpha mode or have a big enough user base, you may legitimately expect to have enough crash reports that you need tools for dealing with them.

Comment: The stack traces is an unsophisticated state machine.  It's just a stack trace -- a singly-linked list.  Matching the variables in each state against some condition is equally trivial.  I don't get the question, since the stack frames are just a singly-linked list.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are talking about "a random puddle of variables". In what I'm proposing, I wouldn't even have that much. The only thing I'm proposing looking at is the addresses that would be executed upon return.

Comment: What I'm proposing is for dealing with automatic crash reports (e.i. every time an assert fails, it sends a bunch of data to a server). I'm basing my idea on the assumption that many bugs do not manifest at the site of the bug but rather are detected somewhere else, so rather than just keep track of the assert that failed, it keeps the whole stack. I'm assuming that these will form a pattern of; a string of calls from main to the bug, a string of calls relating to the bug and a string of calls that aren't the but but are effected by it. Only the middle bit might be unique to each bug.

Comment: @BCS: "I'm assuming that these will form a pattern"  I doubt they will form a "pattern" of any kind.  You can -- given enough information about the program -- determine a root cause.  But there won't be any "pattern".  There will be duplicates (known bugs) and non-duplicates (distinct, irreproducible bugs).  Unless you analyze the actual code, the states of the variables are just random values.

Comment: @BCS: The variables *are* the state of the program.  The address is even less useful for determining the crash.  That will not form any "pattern" at all.  It will either match or it won't.  The call stack is just a list of addresses that either match or don't.  There's no "pattern", just exact matches or not.  Analyze some real crash dumps before wasting too much more time on this.

Comment: Ahhh! I think I see where we are thinking differently. I'm **NOT** thinking of this as a diagnostic tool. It would not be used for finding the reason or root cause of a bug, but only as a heuristic for partitioning program failure incidents by common causes (root and/or proximal).

Comment: As for patterns vs. only exact matches; One trivial case that most definitely results in a pattern is an inadvertent infinite indirect recursion. The prefix will start with `main` but can differ hugely for different trigger cases of the same bug. (Oh, and I have looked at a number of crashes so I at least have *some* clue as to what I'm talking about :)

Comment: @BCS: "partitioning program failure incidents" still makes no sense to me.  Please update your question to provide some examples or something.  Failure tracebacks are trivially available in languages like Java and Python.  You don't need any tools at all to parse them; they're directly available in an exception handler.  They trivially form exact matches.  A particular line of code is a known failure.  There's no subtlety or "pattern matching" to this.  Please UPDATE the question with some kind of tangible example. If you've examined dumps, use REAL dumps.

Answer (score 0):

The return pointer on the stack is just a pointer to memory. In theory if you look at the call stack of a program that just makes one function call, the return pointer (for that one function) can have different value for every execution of the program. How would you analyze that?

In theory you could read through a core dump using a map file. But doing so is extremely platform and compiler specific. You would not be able to create a general tool for doing this with any program. Read your compiler's documentation to see if it includes any tools for doing postmortem analysis.

Comment: Position independent code aside (like in a DLL/so) the location of executable code is fixed at compile time. (Note I'm not looking at the frame pointer but the instruction pointer.) Also, I think that the location of even DLL code is only a function of the versions of the libraries loaded and if it isn't, then a little work would even be able to back-out that. In short, replace literal return pointers with line numbers and nothing I care about changes